# How to get all markers on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a listener that will detect changes of the location of objects on databases. It will pass all the information of the object that is being changed.

I want to get all markers from the current map and find the marker that is affected. Once found, update the location.

But, I am still looking for the best ways to get all markers from the map and then I can update the location.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([37.78541,-122.40787], 13);
var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
var mapLink =
    '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer(
    'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/examples.map-i87786ca/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2Vja29iIiwiYSI6IndzVjRGN0kifQ.lToORsjE0lkt-VQ2SXOb-Q', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);

var marker = createCircleMarker([44.977368, -93.232659]);
marker._id = "69"; // Id of the marker
map.addLayer(marker);
var socket = io();

socket.on('update location', function(obj) {
     // Get all markers and find markers with attribute obj.name to 
     // update the location to [obj.lat,obj.lon]

});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `eachLayer` method on L.map. Like

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) { 
    if (layer.options.name === 'XXXXX') {
        layer.setLatLng([newLat,newLon])
    } 
});
```

Documentation at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-eachlayer

Comment: this function will retreive just the leaflet object you currently see in the screen. not whole objects on the map that you currently not see.

Answer (score 3):

To add an option without using `map.eachLayer`; all layers within the map are internally stored in `map._layers`.

Use

```
map._layers.forEach(function (layer) {
  ...
});
```

to iterate over **ALL** Layer elements. Not just the ones currently visible.

Comment: In my version of leaflet `map._layers` is a dictionary, not an array. So `forEach` function doesnt exist

Comment: Maybe has received an update regarding that manner. Feel free to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the DOM elements (image icons, marker-clusters, etc.) and get the hidden leaflet ID that is undocumentedly attached to it. Select it in the [ DevTools › Elements ] panel and enter `$0._leaflet_id` or `console.dir($0)` to see for yourself.

Use that ID to reference the object version of that element in your map leaflet object: `leaflet_object = map._targets[leafletId]`.

Try if that works for you.

If you have marker clusters, you might have to go through each layer and get all those hidden child markers.

```js
$('.marker-cluster').each((index, el) => {
  let markers = map._targets?.[el._leaflet_id]?.getAllChildMarkers() ?? [];
  // … do something with those markers
});
```